# About hokuyo_node's Transform

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find where the frame name is defined.

I launched hokuyo_node and rviz.
Floor Scan(Laser scan) data was visualized when Fixed Frame is set to "/laser".
Where the frame name "/laser" is defined ?
I checked through source codes in hokuyo_node package,
however I couldn't find where it is.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44297/about-hokuyo_node%27s-transform/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a private parameter named ~frame_id.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node#Parameters

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to broadcast that frame yourself, either in [code](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) or using [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher) or creating a urdf and use [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot). See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) for some basic tf setup.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2